# Proof a sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given 2 sequences $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$ such that:
$${y_n^{2} \leq \frac{1}{n} + {x_n}{y_n} \sqrt[3]{x_n}}$$  with ${\forall} n \in$ $ \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose that ${x_n} \to 0$. Prove that $\{y_n\}$ converges and calculate ${\lim_{n\to\infty} {y_n} }$

I tried to do something like this:
$${y_n^{2} \leq \frac{1}{n} + {x_n}{y_n} \sqrt[3]{x_n}}$$
$$\equiv {y_n}({y_n} - x_n^{\frac{4}{3}}) \leq {\frac{1}{n}}$$

Because ${x_n} \to 0$, so that $x_n^{\frac{4}{3}} \to 0$, so that the left side of the inequality ${y_n}({y_n} - x_n^{\frac{4}{3}}) \to {y_n^2}$.
And, because ${y_n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ so that $y_n$ is bounded and exist ${\lim_{n\to\infty} {y_n} }$.

Is that a good way to solve the first part of problem ? And how to calculate the limit ?

P/s: Sorry because my problem with English and thanks for helping !!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Suppose that it is **not** the case that $~\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n ~$ is equal to $~\pm \infty.~$  In other words, suppose that you can prove that $~|y_n|~$ does not grow unbounded.  Then, you have that the second term in the definition of $~\left(y_n\right)^2~$ must go to $~0.$

Answer (score 4):

For every $n > 0$, let $P_n : X \mapsto X^2 - Xx_n \sqrt[3]{x_n} - \dfrac{1}{n}$.

The hypothesis is that $P_n(y_n) \leq 0$ for every $n$.

But the roots of $P_n$ are exactly $\dfrac{x_n\sqrt[3]{x_n} \pm \sqrt{x_n^{8/3}+\frac{4}{n}}}{2}$, so the fact that $P_n(y_n) \leq 0$ gives
$$\dfrac{x_n\sqrt[3]{x_n} - \sqrt{x_n^{8/3}+\frac{4}{n}}}{2}\leq y_n \leq \dfrac{x_n\sqrt[3]{x_n} + \sqrt{x_n^{8/3}+\frac{4}{n}}}{2}$$

Now you can squeeze.

Answer (score 3):

Observe ($\sqrt{\cdot}$ is cubic root),

$$ y^2_n \leq \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{|x_n \sqrt{x_n}|}{2}(y_n^2+1) \implies y_n^2\left(1 -\frac{|x_n \sqrt{x_n}|}{2}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n} +  \frac{|x_n \sqrt{x_n}|}{2}. $$

For $n$ big enough

$$ \frac{y_n^2}{2} \leq y_n^2 \left(1 -\frac{|x_n \sqrt{x_n}|}{2} \right) \leq  \frac{1}{n} + \frac{|x_n \sqrt{x_n}|}{2} \rightarrow 0$$